# Java Spring - creating a single session for user handling

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-boot

I am working on an application and I may have come across a bug in the session handling.

Essentially there is login user, logout user and get stored user.

-- but I think when I invoked the functions it would create a different session each time? So I am trying to create a controller that could create ONE session and read from this.. but I am getting errors like - change getSession to static..

in my main application how would I make calls to these functions and just pass one session throughout?

session controller looks like this.

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SessionController extends HttpServlet{

    HttpServletRequest request;

    SessionController(HttpServletRequest request){      
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    }

    HttpSession getSession(){
        HttpSession session = this.request.getSession(true);        
        return session;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static JSONObject getLoggedUser() {
        session = getSession();

        JSONObject user = (JSONObject) session.getAttribute("user");

        System.out.println("session getLoggedUser>>>"+session);
        System.out.println("---session login user>>>"+session.getAttribute("user"));

        return user;
    }   

    public static void logUser(JSONObject object) {
        session = getSession();
        //store user details
        session.setAttribute("user", object);

        System.out.println("session login>>>"+session());
        System.out.println("---session login user>>>"+session.getAttribute("user"));
    }

    public static void logOutUser() {
        session = getSession();
        session.removeAttribute("user");

        System.out.println("session logout>>>"+session);
        System.out.println("---session login user>>>"+session.getAttribute("user"));
    }

}
```

and in MyService I have a login method like this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> login(
        @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email,
        @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password, 
        HttpServletRequest request
        ) throws  Exception {

            System.out.println("email email>>>"+email);
            System.out.println("email password>>>"+password);

            //find matching account with email
            TblLogin checkAccount = tblLoginRepository.findByEmail(email);

            if (checkAccount != null) {     
                //do the passwords match
                if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, checkAccount.getPassword())) {
                    // Encode new password and store it
                    System.out.println("PASSWORD MATCH");

                    //build clean user object
                    JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject();

                    //create user object
                    userDetails.put("id", checkAccount.getId());
                    userDetails.put("email", checkAccount.getEmail());
                    userDetails.put("password", checkAccount.getPassword());
                    userDetails.put("pin", checkAccount.getPin());

                        //attempt look up to get patient information and append to response
                        try {
                            TblPatient extInformation = tblPatientRepository.findByPatientID(checkAccount.getPin());

                            userDetails.put("forename", extInformation.getForename());
                            userDetails.put("surname", extInformation.getSurname());
                            userDetails.put("dateOfBirth", extInformation.getDateOfBirth());
                            userDetails.put("genderID", extInformation.getGenderID());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            userDetails.put("forename", null);
                            userDetails.put("surname", null);
                            userDetails.put("dateOfBirth", null);
                            userDetails.put("genderID", null);
                        }

                    //store user in session
                    SessionController mySession = new SessionController(request);
                    mySession.logUser(userDetails);

                    //userDetails.put("session", session);
                    //System.out.println("session>>>"+session.getAttribute("user"));
                    //System.out.println("newAcc>>>"+checkAccount);

                    JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "success", "User found login succesful");                           
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

                } else {
                    //create error response                         
                    JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "error", "User passwords do not match");
                    //System.out.println("user PASSWORD error >>>"+response);
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            } else{
                //create error response
                JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "error", "User has not been found");
                //System.out.println("user does not exist >>>"+response);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
            }               
}
```

would I need to do something like

```
HttpSession mySession = new SessionController();
```

---

update 1.

I've got the latest code base looking like this.

getHome
-- will do a look up on the stored user in session

login
-- will CREATE the user in session

logout 
-- will DELETE the user in session

MyService class -- now I need to stash mySession as a global variable - and get it built JUST ONCE? Where in the MyService controller but it needs the request?

```
package controller;


@RestController
public class MyService {


    //api/getHome
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/api/getHome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> getHome(
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws Exception { 


            SessionController mySession = new SessionController(request);
            JSONObject user = mySession.getLoggedUser();
            System.out.println("logged in user"+ user);


                //get Home Data
                MyApiHome myApiHome = new MyApiHome();
                JSONArray data = myApiHome.getHomeData();
                System.out.println("myHomedata"+ data);

                JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(data, "success", "Fetching home data");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
            //getHome service 
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password, 
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws  Exception {

                System.out.println("email email>>>"+email);
                System.out.println("email password>>>"+password);

                //find matching account with email
                TblLogin checkAccount = tblLoginRepository.findByEmail(email);

                if (checkAccount != null) {     
                    //do the passwords match
                    if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, checkAccount.getPassword())) {
                        // Encode new password and store it
                        System.out.println("PASSWORD MATCH");

                        JSONObject userDetails = getUserData(checkAccount);


                        //store user in session 
                        SessionController mySession = new SessionController(request);
                        JSONObject user = mySession.logUser(userDetails);
                        System.out.println("logged in user"+ user);

                        JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "success", "User found login succesful");                           
                        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

                    } else {
                        //create error response                         
                        JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "error", "User passwords do not match");
                        //System.out.println("user PASSWORD error >>>"+response);
                        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
                    }
                } else{
                    //create error response
                    JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "error", "User has not been found");
                    //System.out.println("user does not exist >>>"+response);
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
                }               
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws  Exception {

            //List<TblLogin> acc = (List<TblLogin>) session.getAttribute("user");
            //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            //session.removeAttribute("user");          

            //log user out of session
        //SessionController.logOutUser(request);

    SessionController mySession = new SessionController(request);
    JSONObject user = mySession.logOutUser();

            //create success response
            JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "success", "User logged out");                          
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

this is what my SessionController looks like.

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SessionController {

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    SessionController(HttpServletRequest request){      
        //HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        this.request = request;
    }   

    HttpSession getSession(){
        HttpSession session =  this.request.getSession(true);   
        return session;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JSONObject getLoggedUser() {
        HttpSession session = getSession();

        JSONObject user = (JSONObject) session.getAttribute("user");

        System.out.println("session getLoggedUser>>>"+session);
        System.out.println("---session login user>>>"+session.getAttribute("user"));

        return user;
    }   

    public JSONObject logUser(JSONObject object) {
        HttpSession session = getSession();
        //store user details
        session.setAttribute("user", object);

        JSONObject storedUser = (JSONObject) session.getAttribute("user");
        System.out.println("session login>>>"+session);
        System.out.println("---session login user>>>"+storedUser);

        return storedUser;
    }

    public void logOutUser() {
        HttpSession session = getSession();
        session.invalidate();
        //session.removeAttribute("user");

        System.out.println("session logout>>>"+session);
        System.out.println("---session login user>>>"+session.getAttribute("user")); 
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: session login>>>org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@265a053e
session getLoggedUser>>>org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@349a0282

Comment: so the session is different right? StandardSessionFacade@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue by creating the session just ONCE. So what was happening was I was unintentionally getting/setting a new session instead of just reviewing the one session.

-- so the session controller is fairly simple..

SessionController.java

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class SessionController {

    SessionController(){      
    }   

    public static JSONObject getLoggedUser(HttpSession session) {
        JSONObject storedUser = (JSONObject) session.getAttribute("user");
        return storedUser;
    }   

    public static JSONObject logUser(JSONObject object, HttpSession session) {
        //store user details
        session.setAttribute("user", object);
        JSONObject storedUser = (JSONObject) session.getAttribute("user");
        return storedUser;
    }

    public static JSONObject logOutUser(HttpSession session) {
        session.invalidate();
        return null;
    }
}
```

now on my Service controller -- this is where I create one session and then pump that session through these session methods.

MyService.java

```
package controller;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import services.MailService;
import services.SimpleEmailService;
import domain.TblLogin;
import repo.TblLoginRepository;

import domain.TblPatient;
import repo.TblPatientRepository;

@RestController
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private Configuration fmConfiguration; 

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;    

    @Autowired
    private TblLoginRepository tblLoginRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TblPatientRepository tblPatientRepository;

    private HttpSession session;

    MyService(){        
    }


    //api/getHome
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/api/getHome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> getHome(
            //HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws Exception {

                try {
                    //get logged in user from session
                    JSONObject user = SessionController.getLoggedUser(this.session);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                }

                //get Home Data
                MyApiHome myApiHome = new MyApiHome();
                JSONArray data = myApiHome.getHomeData();

                JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(data, "success", "Fetching home data");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
            //getHome service 
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password, 
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws  Exception {

                //find matching account with email
                TblLogin checkAccount = tblLoginRepository.findByEmail(email);

                if (checkAccount != null) {

                    //do the passwords match
                    if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, checkAccount.getPassword())) {
                        // Encode new password and store it

                        JSONObject userDetails = getUserData(checkAccount);

                        //create ONE session
                        this.session = request.getSession(true);

                        //store user in session
                        SessionController.logUser(userDetails, this.session);                                           
                        JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "success", "User found login succesful");                           
                        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

                    } else {
                        //create error response                         
                        JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "error", "User passwords do not match");
                        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
                    }
                } else{
                    //create error response
                    JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "error", "User has not been found");
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
                }               
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(
            ) throws  Exception {

            //logout user
            SessionController.logOutUser(this.session);     

            //create success response
            JSONObject response = ResponseWrapper(null, "success", "User logged out");                          
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaken, the session is only created once every after login. The User session is created on your Service class `mySession.logUser(userDetails);`

`session.invalidate()` is much preferred than `session.removeAttribute("user")`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154166/discussion-on-answer-by-kevenlolo-java-spring-creating-a-single-session-for-us). If there is useful information obtained in this discussion, it should be [edit]ed into the answer.

Comment: I'm worried I can't fix this.. I am not sure what I am going to do if I can't store the user in a session.

Comment: I think I fixed it.